# Homestead laravel projects suddenly no write access

Tags: vagrant, file-permissions, homestead

I have a couple of projects on a homestead box.

last week i cloned a project from git and i noticed that when the logger was called the logfile was created and written to but the second time it complained it had no write access.

I didnt pay attention to it much because i was in a hurry, so i just deleted the log everytime.

But now, returning to a laravel 6 project i worked on previously i see the same problem suddenly occur.

This time is different, instead of not being able to write to existing logs, this time its also not able to create the logs.

I did a 777 on the storage dir and the log file error went away but now it complains it cant write session files?!

> ErrorException
> file_put_contents(/home/vagrant/code/laravel6_project/storage/framework/sessions/hA3459VveGgYn761YijeEBcQgNylx0mToIRyLhkR):
> failed to open stream: Permission denied

Why would something that worked fine suddenly break in regard to permissions.

I dont want to go on and chmod 777 everything everytime over and over again.

All files have owner: vagrant:vagrant and this is what it always was as far as i can tell.

anyway, i figured perhaps something changed with an update or something so now in the vagrant machine i tried

**sudo chmod -R vagrant:www-data**

but its being ignored...  folder is still vagrant:vagrant.

stumped...

There are lots of questions on this exact problem with many more times of different suggested solutions but none work for me.

Im starting to suspect the virtual  machine is corrupted or something..

any ideas?

someone suggested to check if perhaps the wrong user was specified in:
/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
perhaps it said **user = www-data** instead of **user = vagrant**

all the other versions like:

> /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
>
> /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
>
> /etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

indeed all had: **user = vagrant** but the /var/log/php7.3-fpm.log says:
**user = www-data**

so i was very confident i had found the problem but after changing it to user=vagrant and restarting apache still the same error.

going nuts...

Answer (score 5):

So,
editing the /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and setting:

> user = vagrant
>   group = vagrant

fixed it , but only after restarting the VM!

simply doing:

> sudo apachectl restart

somehow didn't cut it.

Comment: The correct command to restart PHP FPM should be 
"sudo service php7.3-fpm restart".
Then no need to restart VM.